# Is there a special term for a person who unwittingly creates problems for every one around

Tags: meaning

Which english (american, british, any other flavour; noun or adjective, no matter) term would you use to describe a person who despite of being full of good intentions somehow always manages to make life tougher for all around.

Sometimes just because he is unlucky, sometimes because he lives in his own world and he does not realise how real world ticks, sometimes because he is not able to work in concert with people around (in spite of the fact he wants to work in concert). No matter what is the reason any activity he is engaged in always brings complications and creates problems for other people.

He may be a not unpleasant person but you would certainly prefer not to have him around nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Jinx' would fit the description for this person perfectly.

It is a superstitious term to refer to someone or something, the mere presence or existence of which creates interference or chaos, thus preventing from achieving something or making things complicated. There are other contexts where this term can be used. Like one who brings bad fortune to self or others. Or something or state of something that goes on unchanged for a period of time despite efforts to change it is also referred to as jinx.

Ex. A computer can be referred to as jinxed if it is still not working despite of all the possible troubleshooting done.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jinx

Comment: Thank you. It seems to fit perfectly indeed. I'll mark your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: An alternative is [a jonah](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jonah) part of which definition is _A person who seems to bring bad luck._ Not as common as it used to be but still used occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

The word "jinx" is usually used only in reference to bad luck and not necessarily to the other situations you've listed. I think the word "awkward" covers it a bit better. An awkward person isn't necessarily bad, but they are just uncomfortable to be around. Awkward can refer to both a person being clumsy (as in, they might accidentally bump into people, drop something, etc) or it can refer to their personality (as in, they try to be likeable but they just never quite follow the usual social behavior).

As you've said, an awkward person isn't necessarily unlikeable, but you would prefer not to be around them. :)

Comment: +1 I think this is a better answer. The question, as written, isn't just about bad luck.